# Updating Child records from upadting a field in child record

Tags: apex, trigger, update, after

I have created four contacts for an account.
I want to update child records of an account.If I update lastname in first record of my contacts to 'AAAA'  then the lastname for the remaining three records should be updated to 'BBBB'.
Here is my code.

```
trigger contactlines on account (after insert,after update) {



    List<ID> AccID = New List<ID>();


    for(account acc : Trigger.new){
    if(acc.name!=null&& acc.Id != null){
      AccID.add(acc.Id);
    }


    List<contact> conList = [SELECT id FROM contact WHERE id in :AccID];
    for(integer i = 0 ; i < conList.size(); i++){
       contact con = new contact();
        con.AccountId=acc.Id;
        if(con.LastName=='AAAA'){
            conlist[0].lastname+='BBBB';
        }
    }
    update conList;
    }
}
```

Comment: so - what is the question? what is not working?

Comment: My question is ,I have created four contacts for an account.If i upadted first record's contact latname = 'ABC'   then contact lastname for the last 3 records should be changed to 'XYZ'.

Comment: @mamathaMuthyala hey...are you looking for some logic as in how the last name for other records is 'BBBB' or 'XYZ'?

Comment: anything but if i updated first one last three should be changed to same .ie...      lastname for last three records should be the same...